# Building Tango Unity Examples failing

Tags: google-project-tango

I recently got a Tango tablet device and downloaded the [tango-examples-unity from Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) to start learning. All excited, I opened the MeshBuilder project in Unity and tried to Build it but it failed. My Android SDK and jdk are up to date and the paths are correct as set in Unity preferences. I'm using Unity 5.0.1f on a 64-bit Windows 8 system. Leibniz release notes said they migrated the samples to Unity 5 so I was trying them with Unity 5. Not to say that I didn't get the exact same error in Unity 4.6.3f1 while trying to Build the same project.

Errors:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\path\tango-examples-unity-master\ExperimentalProjects\MeshBuilder\Assets\Plugins\Android\tango-native-service-client-helperlib\bin\aidl\com\google\atap\tangoservice\ITangoLogRequestListener.aidl" or "Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\tango-native-service-client-helperlib\bin\aidl\com\google\atap\tangoservice\ITangoLogRequestListener.aidl"
>
> Error building Player: DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\path\tango-examples-unity-master\ExperimentalProjects\MeshBuilder\Assets\Plugins\Android\tango-native-service-client-helperlib\bin\aidl\com\google\atap\tangoservice\ITangoLogRequestListener.aidl" or "Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\tango-native-service-client-helperlib\bin\aidl\com\google\atap\tangoservice\ITangoLogRequestListener.aidl"

What I've tried so far:

1. Downloading a [different version](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/releases) of the projects. The only project that I was able to build from this other version is PointCloud. Couldn't build anything else.
2. Replacing the included TangoSDK with a new downloaded version of leibniz unity package. This didn't help.
3. Building other projects from the downloaded source code from both urls. No go.
4. Trying this Tango Unity Tutorial from [developers dot google dot com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-depth-perception]. It fails at step "Create a PointCloud object" as no such component is found. I do have the TangoSDK imported so my thinking is that this tutorial probably belongs to an older version of the SDK and won't work for Leibniz. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
5. Tried opening the Kalman version of the PointCloudUnity project. Get an error:

> Opening File failed. It's looking for the /MotionDetectionHelper$MotionDetectionListener.class and not finding it.
>
> Emailing Tango help. No response yet.
>
> Any pointers for getting started with Tango + Unity would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading through this long post and for your help.

Comment: Since I had one project that was building i.e. PointCloud from the second link [https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/releases], and the problem seemed to be related to the Android plugin, I copied over the plugins folder from the PointCloud project into the MeshBuilder project and now my MeshBuilder Builds and I am able to run it on the device as well. Not sure how to mark my question resolved but for now this solution is working for me.

Comment: I just discovered that the actual problem may be Windows related and copying over the plugins folder and MeshBuilder and it working may have been a random event. Turns out my system has an issue with long file names/paths and when I renamed all my in between folders leading up to the project folder, the project build ok. I did install a Windows hotfix for fixing this filename character length issue but that didn't fix the problem. Renaming folders seemingly did. This solution seems to make a little more sense to me than the random copying over of the plugins folder from one project to another.